# Get the parent branch name and commit hash from current feature branch

Tags: git

Branch from `master branch`

```
git checkout -b feature-abc
# update several times on this feature branch.
git add ...; git commit ...  ; git push ...
```

Now I'd like to know how to get its parent branch name (should be `master` branch) and which latest commit I checked out before.

Maybe I merged from master branch several times, I need know the latest commit hash id from its parent branch.

```
master branch

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5-> 
     |         |
     |-> 1 -> ---> 2

feature-abc
```

So currently I am at feature branch (2), how I get the commit hash of 4?

What commands I can run to get these information?

Comment: Branch names do not have parent branch names. They are, in effect, just sticky-note labels attached to commits. The act of making a new commit causes whichever branch is the *current* branch to have its label peeled off the old commit and put on the new one. Many labels can be stuck on a single commit; only one moves (automatically) by the act of committing; and no label has any parent/child relationship with any other label.

Answer (score 2):

```
git rev-list master..feature --boundary
```

will show

- all commit hashes which are on your feature branch but not on master
- the last common commit ("4" in your example) prefixed by a "-"

So if you ignore all lines without a "-", you will find your commit 4.

Since git log is based on git rev-list, you can also use this together with git log, for example:

```
git log master..feature --boundary --oneline
```

is quite informative.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for answer